# Finding Limit Function that satisfies the conditions.

Tags: calculus

I am having some trouble figuring out a few math problems from my Calc 1 class. I am not sure where to start, as all the limits are different.
[image]

70. find a function that satisfies the given conditions and then sketch it.
71. sketch a graph of the function y=f(x) that satisfies the given conditions. Just label the coordinate axes and sketch the appropriate graph.

For 60, 62, and 64 they are kinda the same thing.
[image]
60: would it be a function where if you let X=-1, and the denominator =0, is that what we are looking for? like $ \frac{2}{x+1} \ . $

62. I would say yes, even though g(x) and f(x) are not discontinuous on their own, that changes when you put them in a function together such as $ f(x)/g(x).$
63. not to sure

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: For 60; would 2x/x+1 be an answer since it has a non removable discontinuity at x=-1 ?

Comment: Simple example for 62: $f(x) = 1$, $g(x) = x$. Or, if you want the discontinuity in the interior of $[0,1]$, you can use $g(x) = x - 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just try drawing what the graph could potentially be on paper, and find an equation for it. Here's a freebie for the first one (number 74): $$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-3}$$
Note: I am not taking calculus yet, but I do know about limits and such... I don't know if there is a faster way because my way seems inefficient and not algebraic-like.
EDIT: For the second one, maybe this would work:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}, \ \ \ \ x < 0 \\ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x=0 \\ \frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x > 0 \\ \end{cases}$$
YET ANOTHER EDIT: Your answer for the final one (nonremovable discontinuity) is correct.

Comment: so kinda guess and check? I will try for the second one. was the answer for 60 correct, 2x/x+1 correct?

Comment: @user131785 I think it is... There are many functions that are correct (e.g. $g(x)=\dfrac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}$)

Comment: and that is discontinuous at x=-1 since the denominator would =0 there and we know the discontinuous is not removable since the top and bottom do not cancel fully?

Comment: @user131785 To be totally honest with you I don't really know what a *nonremovable* discontinuity is. I think your answer $\dfrac{2x}{x-1}$ is better because it does not have any factors that can cancel out. I don't know if I am correct, but because my answer has factors that can cancel, it is removable. In any case you are right.

Comment: ah now 1/x-3 was for 74, would would the same 1/x-2 work for 70? seems like it should

Comment: @user131785 I really don't think so because first of all, the graph does not approach $-2$ when it gets to a negative number very close to $0$ like $-0.000001$. See my edited answer, maybe that is a solution?

Comment: ah thank you, that looks pretty good, hopefully itll work

Comment: that actually cant work, since if you plug 0 in you do not get 0 for x=0

Comment: @user131785 The second part of the function says that if $x=0$, $f(x)=0$. That means that $f(0)=0$, which meets the requirement for the function. If you still do not believe me, click [here](http://www.desmos.com/calculator) to go to Desmos Graphing Calculator, type a curly brace `{` in one of the boxes, and enter this piece of text inside the curly braces: `x<0:-1/(x^2+0.5),x=0:0,x>0:1/(x^2+0.5)`. The graph should show, and you will see that $(0,0)$ is a point on the graph.

Comment: but how about for the - and + infinity?

Comment: @user131785 Just plot the graph at the website I told you about and you should see that $f(x)$ approaches $0$ when $x \to \pm\infty$